# Executing Code After Multiple AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Before this is marked as a duplicate, I've looked at several articles on stackoverflow and they don't seem to answer my question.

I'm building a plugin with an api that uses http requests for its calls.  I've got a main loop that executes several times with multiple different AJAX requests inside of it.  I need to be able to execute code once all the requests are complete.

The main issue I'm having is that the array holding all the promise objects is either empty or mostly empty by the time the `$.when` function is reached, causing the code to fire before everything is finished.

Here's the basic, simplified outline of the code:

```
var xhrs = [];
var xhr = null;

$.each(array, function(index, el) {
    // Step 1
    xhr = ajaxCall.success(function() {
        xhr = ajaxCall2();
        xhrs.push(xhr);
    });
    xhrs.push(xhr);

    // Step 2
    xhr = $.getJSON(params, function() {
        //...stuff...

        // Step 3
        var xhrs2 = [];
        $.each(function() {
            xhr = ajaxCall3();
            xhrs.push(xhr);
            xhrs2.push(xhr);
        });

        // Step 4
        xhr = ajaxCall4().success(function() {
            xhr = ajaxCall5().success(function() {
                //....
            });
            xhrs.push(xhr);
        });
        xhrs.push(xhr);


        // Step 5
        $.when(xhrs2).then(function() {
            $.each(function() {
                xhr = ajaxCall5();
                xhrs.push(xhr);
            });
        });

    });
    xhrs.push(xhr);
});


$.when.apply($, xhrs).then(function() {
    // Run when all ajax calls completed
});
```

I've tried moving it around to different locations and no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look how promises work here: https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/

Comment: Stop pushing the promises to the array inside the callbacks, and don't use the same variable name for everything.

Comment: Does it not work just to count the number of requests, and as each one completes increment a number, then do an if `complete_requests == number_of_requests`. I may be over simplifying it.

Comment: @dartanian300 - for a recent project i ended up basically writing a piece of code that inspects the status and after I've reached a loop count that equals the length of the array I know its all done and THEN and only then do I advance to the next function.   good luck

Comment: @Djave no, I don't think that will work because pretty much everything it's working with is a variable number and I wouldn't be able to get a total until after several AJAX calls

Comment: @adeneo ok, how would I test for the promises then?

Comment: First of all, the functions you're calling, like `ajaxCall3` has to actually return promises. Secondly, you're basically doing it the right way, but you should be using the `var` keyword when you declare a variable, and don't use the same name for every variable, use `xhr1`, `xhr2`  etc. instead to make sure you don't overwrite stuff. Thirdly, pushing `xhr` into the array inside the success callback makes no sense, by that time the ajax call has already completed, you have to push the promises to the array outside the callbacks.

Comment: @adeneo all of my `ajaxCall` functions do return promises.  My variables aren't actually `xhr1` and `xhr2`, those are just for the simplified example above.  I didn't think using the same variable to hold individual promises would be an issue which is why there's not a var for each xhr.  There should have been one a the beginning though, I must've forgotten it in the example.  Also, I get the xhr not working in callbacks, but I'm not sure how to wait for them without doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function takes each of the XHRs as arguments, then you can respond in the `then` of the `when`. Each of the responses is passed as a separate argument.

```
$.when(xhr1, xhr2, xhr3).then(function(resp1, resp2, resp3) {
    // All 3 XHRs finished
});
```

Comment: @dartanian300 No you don't, your `then` doesn't use the responses that are passed to it

Comment: @Juan_Mendes_1 I see what you're saying.  However, I don't want to have to write out all my code to be parameters.  Would it still work with `$.when.apply()...`?

Comment: @dartanian300 It's hard to tell, your code looks really messy by reusing arrays inside the callbacks within loops. Follow adeneos's advice in the comments

Comment: @Juan_Mendes I'm new to code using this many AJAX calls and I'm not sure what best practice would be.  The only arrays i'm using are 2 that hold 2 different sets of promise objects and the loops are necessary for the application.  The arrays aren't set in stone and are only the way i'm trying to execute the final piece of code.

Comment: You have to better explain explain what is going on. Which calls need to wait for other calls before they can be made. You are making the same calls twice (`xhr = ajaxCall4().success(function() {xhr=ajaxCall4().success(function() {`). Another one, your step 5 is wrong, `$.when(xhrs2)` should be `$.when.apply($, xhr2)` as you did in the end. To be honest, you need to debug it on your own, add breakpoints and come up with a real (simplified) example of what part is broken, the pseudocode you have is just not comprehensible

Comment: @Juan_Mendes Sorry, that second `ajaxCall4` should be `ajaxCall5`. I've fixed it now.  Maybe the `$.when(xhrs2)` is the issue.  I'm working off some code that isn't my own, so that is probably also part of the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried making every request synchronous? A simple synchronous request in jquery looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url:    'http://example.com' ,
     success: function(result) {
                      //Do stuff with result
              },
     async:   false
});
```

Comment: Synchronous requests block the UI, it's really bad idea. Moreover, they're deprecated. https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning